# What does "any scanf non-assignable conversion" mean?

Tags: errorformat

`:help errorformat` lists the basic items supported in 'errorformat' and one of them is:

> %*{conv}    any scanf non-assignable conversion

What does that mean and how can I use it?

---

The [fscanf documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) says:

> Each conversion specification has the following format:
>
> - introductory % character
> - (optional) assignment-suppressing character *. If this option is present, the function does not assign the result of the conversion to any receiving argument.
> - ...
> - conversion format specifier

It sounds like `%*c` would suppress assignment to a character, which sounds like a non assigned conversion to me. I assume it would consume that character without including it in the quickfix entry. However, using `:set efm=%*c%m|cgetbuffer` gives "E375: Unsupported %c in format string."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After studying the historical (back to vim 2.0) and current source code and documentation, I have concluded the doc is *wrong*.  More precisely, it is out of date by more than 20 years.

#### The doc is wrong

`errorformat` plainly does not support "any scanf non-assignable conversion" and this fact is known to the author, given by a comment in `src/quickfix.c`:

```
// TODO: scanf()-like: %*ud, %*3c, %*f, ... ?
```

In implementation, vim does not actually use scanf or any of its variants and differences are to be expected (despite the doc's suggestion).

#### What does work

So which `{conv}` are actually valid?

vim supports `%*[^a-z0-9]`, i.e., regex-like character classes.  This matches with scanf's usage of `[set]`, although vim's is more general.  Additionally, due to implementation details, vim supports any backslash character group like `%*\d`.  This is not in line with scanf, but could be useful.

#### What happened here?

At at one time vim did actually use `sscanf` and thus the doc comment was correct (at least for a particular set of versions of `sscanf`). However, in vim 5.4, the code was rewritten* to use a custom implementation which instead builds a regex pattern from the `errorformat`.  `%*<>` was not fully implemented and the `TODO` above was added.

*I do not know why exactly this was done, except for a passing comment in the source code that mentions `sscanf` might sometimes be slow.

Comment: thanks for digging back that far. How about creating a issue/PR for that?